# Add a row if the following row has a specific value R

Tags: r, dataset, row, addition

I have a big dataset that in its short version looks like this:

```
Time    L_Diam_x    Trigger sample_rate
505381380   -0.9935 3200    4001
505385381   -0.9934 3200    4002
505389383   -0.9934 3200    4001
505393384   -0.9937 3200    4002
505397386   -0.9939 3200    4001
505401387   -0.9938 3200    8000
505409387   -0.9934 3200    4001
```

I want to find all values more than 5000 in the the column **sample_rate** and insert a new row after each row like that. That new row should contain zeros in the rest of colums except the column **Time**. For the **Time** column in the new row the value should be equal **previous value in the Time column + 4001**. So, the end data set will look like this:

```
Time    L_Diam_x    Trigger sample_rate
505381380   -0.9935 3200    4001
505385381   -0.9934 3200    4002
505389383   -0.9934 3200    4001
505393384   -0.9937 3200    4002
505397386   -0.9939 3200    4001
505401387   -0.9938 3200    4000
505405387         0    0    4000
505409387   -0.9934 3200    4000
```

What is the easiest way to solve this non-trivial problem?

Comment: partition the dataframe based on sample_rate > 5000. Duplicte the dataframe that has values greater than 5000, in one of the copies, mutate all its non-time columns to be zero and then add 4001 to its time column. Then bind_rows to bring all three pieces back together. You haven't even given a way to generate example data let alone shown an attempt, so I'm unwilling to give explicit code.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` I filter all those with sample rate > 5000 then add 4001 to the time and `rbind`.  Sample_rate is specified as 4000 because you didn't say what to do with that column.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(sample_rate > 5000) %>% mutate(Time = Time+4001, L_Diam_x = 0, Trigger = 0, sample_rate = 4000) %>% rbind(df) %>% arrange(Time)

#        Time L_Diam_x Trigger sample_rate
# 1 505381380  -0.9935    3200        4001
# 2 505385381  -0.9934    3200        4002
# 3 505389383  -0.9934    3200        4001
# 4 505393384  -0.9937    3200        4002
# 5 505397386  -0.9939    3200        4001
# 6 505401387  -0.9938    3200        8000
# 7 505405388   0.0000       0        4000
# 8 505409387  -0.9934    3200        4001
```